# Magento 2: How to redirect 404 to home?

Tags: magento2, redirect, admin-panel, 404

How can I redirect all my 404 routes to the home page without changing my `.htaccess` file?

I'd like to know some Admin configuration or module.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of doing this, log in to the admin and go to **Stores > Configuration > General > Web** and change the drop-down value for **CMS No Route Page** in the Default Pages section. You should be able to select your CMS Home Page like the image below:

[image: Magento 2 CMS No Route Page]

Comment: I followed this, but its not changing upon clicking save