# Redirect 404 Pages To the Homepage

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, 404-page, home-page

We have disabled products, categories, and CMS. When we try to access the URL it redirects 404 page.

I want to redirect 404 pages to the Homepage of the site.

Comment: Please, read this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207490/magento-2-how-to-redirect-404-to-home

Comment: Yes it redirect s to the homepage but it shows the blank homepage only categories not remaining content of the homepage